# Is vSphere vMA installed on the server, or remote client?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I am doing a bit of research into ESX vs ESXi and am not entirely sure if vMA is part of the management console running next to the vmkernel in ESXi, or a remote tool that interfaces with the management console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is vSphere vMA installed on the
>   server, or remote client?

Neither. vSphere Management Assistant is a virtual machine that you deploy inside your VMWare environment.

It is a remote tool that interfaces with your VMWare environment.

Comment: So what is running the virtual machine? It is run by the hypervisor that is running all of the other servers you have virtualized?